# How to convert list to dictionary with first word like this?

Tags: python

I want to convert list to dictionary with a like this

```
givenlist = [
  'Asia:ASIA,IN,CN,KR,JP', 
  'Europe:DE,EUROPE'
]
```

to

```
{
  'Asia': ['ASIA','IN','CN','KR','JP'], 
  'Europe': ['DE','EUROPE']
}
```

Can I do this with using comprehension?

I tried to use list comprehension but it didn't work..

Comment: What did you try? How didn't it work?

Comment: I think I'm not good at with list comprehension. I tried for like 5 hours but with a wrong way

Comment: _Show_ us those ways and we will have a much better idea of where you are stuck and what to explain. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: (To create a dictionary, you want a dictionary comprehension.)

Answer (score 4):

```
{
  item.split(':', 1)[0]: item.split(':', 1)[1].split(',') 
  for item in givenlist
}
```

Comment: You want to limit to a single split with `item.split(":", 1)` in case the data list contains literal colons, too.

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary comprehension method can be cleaned up quite a bit, breaking this down step by step.

```
>>> givenlist = ['Asia:ASIA,IN,CN,KR,JP', 'Europe:DE,EUROPE']
>>> {
...   k: country_codes
...   for x in givenlist
...   for k, v in [x.split(':', 1)]
...   for country_codes in [v.split(',')]
... }
{'Asia': ['ASIA', 'IN', 'CN', 'KR', 'JP'], 'Europe': ['DE', 'EUROPE']}
```

Note that by giving the argument `1` to `str.split` we ensure the initial split only happens at most one time.

Answer (score 0):

If you use regex, you can split on everything in one call, and use a couple of walruses to manage it.

```
expr = __import__('re').compile(r'[:,]').split

data = ['Asia:ASIA,IN,CN,KR,JP', 'Europe:DE,EUROPE']

rslt = {k:v for d in data if (k := (v := expr(d)).pop(0))}

print(rslt)
```

###### output

```
{'Asia': ['ASIA', 'IN', 'CN', 'KR', 'JP'], 'Europe': ['DE', 'EUROPE']}
```